# 504 Gateway Time-out on GRPC

Tags: go, grpc

I am learning rpc&grpc and go now, i was confused by the grpc.

When I was learning the examples on GitHub（https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples）, I encountered some problems. In server, i use `address = "ip:50051"`  instead of `address = ":50051"`(ip is my intranet ip), and in client i use  `address = "ip:50051"`  instead of `address= "localhost:50051"`, then run the server and the client, in client i get the error:

`rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing failed to do connect handshake, response: \"HTTP/1.0 504 Gateway Time-out\\r\\nConnection: close`

But when i learn rpc in golang, use my intranet ip in the server and client, it is ok.

So i want to know why it is wrong in the grpc?

Comment: try `0.0.0.0:50051`, that will listen on all interfaces at port 50051 which is generally what you want

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak ths, i try `0.0.0.0:50051` in server, but it is not ok. i use `myInetIp:50051` in client, also get the same error like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the client failed to on proxy (failed to do a [HTTP Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_method) handshake).

If you have proxy enabled in your system (the proxy environment variable, `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY`, is set), make sure the proxy works.

If you don't need proxy, clear the env variables and try again.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i change the network, and solved the problem.